# Uploading sketch in Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino

I am  working on making an interface between MATLAB and Arduino. In other words, I want to send some data from MATLAB to Arduino. I have written programs both in MATLAB and the Arduino IDE.

MATLAB program:

```
c = 1;
if (c ~= 0 )
    f = 1;
else     
    disp('vhxhjf');
end
disp(f)

arduino=serial('COM5','BaudRate',9600);   % create serial communication object on port COM4      
fopen(arduino); % initiate arduino communication
while f
   fprintf(arduino,'%s',char(f)); % send answer variable content to arduino   
end 
fclose(arduino); % end communication with arduino
```

Code for Arduino:

```
int ledPin = 13;
int matlabData ;
void setup() { 
   pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   // turn the LED on when we're done
   // digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}
void loop() {  
  if(Serial.available() > 0 ) {
    matlabData = Serial.read();
    if ( matlabData != 0) {
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13,LOW);
     delay(1000);
    }
    else
    digitalWrite(13,LOW); 
  }     
}
```

The problem is whenever I am uploading the sketch , this error is being thrown regularly in arduino ide:

```
 avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM5": The system cannot find the file specified
```

It was works on the first try, but after that the above error is thrown continuosly .

Also in matlab, after the first try , the following error is thrown:

```
enter code here
    Error using serial/fopen (line 72)
    Open failed: Port: COM5 is not available. No ports are available.
    Use INSTRFIND to determine if other instrument objects are connected    to        requested device.

    Error in SP (line 65)
    fopen(arduino); % initiate arduino communication

  >> instrfind

    Instrument Object Array

     Index:    Type:     Status:   Name:  
      1         serial    open      Serial-COM5
      2         serial    closed    Serial-COM5
```

and also the command `instrfind` is showing that the com5 port is closed after the first try.

I have tried the solution given in this link but it is didn't work:
  http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=48421.0

Comment: i also checked the serial port and board in arduino ide. they are both correct .i.e arduino uno and com5

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you don't close the port.

In your code,  when do you close it? When is `f` changed so the loop exits?

According to [these people](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/249818), you can try to do

```
delete(instrfindall)
```

before trying to open the port or

```
fopen(arduino);
closeFID = onCleanup(@() fclose(arduino));
...
```

IMHO the second solution looks better (less destructive)

BTW: put a delay or a sleep (I don't know how this is done in ML) in the `fprintf` loop, otherwise you will send too many data to the poor Arduino...